# Java Basic I want to prompt user 9 digit zip code

Tags: java, string

I am very new to Java, but I am really enthusiastic to learn it. I would like to solve the problem by myself step by step

I tried to do my homework piece by piece.

I want to ask users to put 9 digit zip code, for example 701152014, not for 5 digit like 70115.

I wanted to keep asking users until they type 9 digits like 701152014

if they put 5 digits I want to keep asking please type 9 digit.

I use NetBean.

System.out.println(zipNew);  This part, something wrong with it.it says error.

so I wanted to prompt user until users would type 9 digit zip code.

how can I do that? Thank you so much.

Thank you so much for teaching me. I really would like to learn Java. Thank you.

```
    package week7;



    import javax.swing.*;

    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args){

        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);     

        String zip=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your zip");
            String zipNew;
            int ziplength = (zip.length());

            if (ziplength == 9){
                  zipNew = zip;
                 }
            else if (ziplength !=9)
    {
    String zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"please type 9 digit zip code not 5 digit");   //----this part is wrong
    }
   System.out.println(zipNew);  //----this part is wrong, 
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind expanding on what *exactly* is wrong in the body of the question? It's buried in your code and could be easy to miss. In addition, you don't specify *how* it's wrong -- we can't read your mind.

Comment: I am really sorry, I add more details. I am really sorry.

Comment: It's better, but still missing something. *What* error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I'd use a `JFormattedField` and/or `DocumentFilter`, but lets keep it simple...

The basic idea is, you need to loop until you get what you need, for example...

```
String zip = null;
do {
    zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your zip");
} while (zip != null && zip.length() < 9);

System.out.println("zip = " + zip);
```

This will loop until the user presses [Cancel] or the value they enter has 9 characters.  You need to beware, this can result in `zip` been equal to `null` and you will need to check for this.  Also, there is nothing stopping the user from entering non-numeric values...

Take a closer look at [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you so much. I try to learn everything from online, but I have not been able to find this solution. It was really hard for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the formatting is terrible. Not sure if it occurred when posting it here and you didn't actually use that formatting, but you might wanna make it more readable.

You declare the String zip twice. You can't have two variables of the same name in the same class, so in your else if condition (you don't need the if ziplength != 9 as the else guarantees that condition is true) change the name of the String or don't declare the variable again (e.g. say zip = blahblah not String zip = blahblah in the else).

To answer your question, use a do-while loop. Here's an example:

```
String zip;
do {
zip = blahblah
} while (zip.length != 9)
```

Comment: Thank you for lecturing me. My professor just want to know I am done homework or not. I really appreciate your suggestion!!!!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that in the line :

```
 int ziplength = (zip.length());
```

You are simply not getting the length of `zipNew`, but instead the length of zip, which doesn't appear to have been declared anywhere.

I would suggest changing this line to :

```
int ziplength = (zipNew.length());
```

I have very little experience with java, but just from broad understanding of other languages, I believe you've just made a simple mistake.

Hope this works!
Cheers,

Mike

Comment: Thank you, I am really glad to learn so many ways. It helps me to learn coding. Thank you so much!!!